# Wait n seconds before bootstrap, Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm making a space/gravity game in Angular 2 - and currently want to have a splash screen before the mainmenu component loads.

I figure the easiest way would be to simply use the pre-bootstrapped index.html contents, as such:

```
<body>
    <!-- 
        //This is where our bootstrapped content will go. 
        //Because everything will be removed from the DOM after bootstrap,
        //we can consider this pre-bootstrapped index.html as a psuedo "splash screen"
        //(anim credit @ http://codepen.io/katehummer/pen/zrygBM)
    -->
    <!--<app-mainmenu>-->
    <svg class="solar-system">
        <circle id="sun" cx="100" cy="100" r="10" stroke="none" fill="#FFE581" />
        <circle id="mercury" cx="100" cy="100" r="3" fill="#fff" stroke="none" />
        <circle id="venus" cx="100" cy="100" r="4" fill="#fff" stroke="none" />
        <circle id="earth" cx="100" cy="100" r="5" fill="#fff" stroke="none" />
        <circle id="mars" cx="100" cy="100" r="5" fill="#fff" stroke="none" />
        <circle id="mercury-orbit" cx="100" cy="100" r="35" fill="none" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="0.5" />
        <circle id="venus-orbit" cx="100" cy="100" r="55" fill="none" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="0.5" />
        <circle id="earth-orbit" cx="100" cy="100" r="75" fill="none" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="0.5" />
        <circle id="mars-orbit" cx="100" cy="100" r="95" fill="none" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="0.5" />
    </svg>


    <!-- 
        //WAIT 10 SECONDS MINIMUM - OR WAIT UNTIL USER LOADS IF AFTER 10 SEC
    -->
    <!--</app-mainmenu>-->
</body>
```

While `<app-mainmenu>` is commented out, I can sucessfully test my animation. It looks just like the one referenced in the comments.

The next step is to tell Angular to wait 10 seconds before bootstrapping. I've tried a delay in JS at the bottom, but since it doesn't block, it didn't work.

```
<script>
    setInterval(tryFinishLoading, 10000);

    function tryFinishLoading() {
        alert("loaded");
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can wait for the following:

1) The user to load, if < 10, go to (2)

2) Wait until 10, if not loaded, loop until loaded.

Cheers!

Comment: How about hiding the root component (app-mainmenu) and showing the animation for 10 seconds and after 10 seconds show the component and hide the animation? Old show/hide tricks with JavaScript!

Comment: Create an angular component Splash. Let it be the first component to bootstrap. You can switch to a different page by navigating to different page after the required amount of delay from the splash component

Comment: @SabbirRahman That's a good idea, but I don't think it's possible, because after the component gets bootstrapped, the previous content is removed from the DOM - so while this would succeed in allowing us to wait 10 seconds before displaying the mainmenu component, the splash screen would be removed from the DOM much earlier than that. :(

Comment: @VinitSarvade that's a good idea, but my main concern with that method is causing excess loading for little benefit - there has to be an easier way, I think.

Comment: @Kevin Well the splash will hold the svg content. So it gets loaded as the first component. Nothing gets removed. You app-menu will remain empty by default. It will hold the splash as soon as angular is bootstrapped

Comment: @Kevin Well it's just another component without any heavy logic. It should be fine. You may feel it to be sluggish but don't worry with angular AoT compilation, production builds will work with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<body>
  <app-mainmenu id="main" style="display:none"></app-mainmenu>
  <svg id="anim">Your Animation</svg>

  <script>
    var anim = document.getElementById('anim');
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    setTimeout(function() {
      anim.style.display = 'none';
      main.style.display = 'block';
    }, 10000);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome, so you are putting the bootstrapped code outside of the splash code, so when it's ready, it doesn't replace the splash code, right?

It works!